# Facebook comments: url "unreachable" with 503 error for no reason

Tags: debugging, comments, facebook-comments

Yes, I read all of the other similar threads.  My OG tags are perfect, my server handles the HTTP range header fine, etc.

The URL http://www.prophotoblogs.com/blog/auto-update-1289/ when put in the debugger:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.prophotoblogs.com%2Fblog%2Fauto-update-1289%2F

Says it gets a 503 code, and that the "Document returned no data" when you ask to see exactly what the scraper sees.

But, the page loads perfectly, and if you curl it with the FB user-agent, everything is perfect.  I ran all of these tests, and they returned perfectly:

```
curl --user-agent "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" "http://www.prophotoblogs.com/blog/auto-update-1289/"
curl -I -H 'Range: bytes=0-40960' --user-agent "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" 'http://www.prophotoblogs.com/blog/auto-update-1289/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...I don't see a `503`, and I also don't see that your "OG tags are perfect":

[Facebook Lint](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.prophotoblogs.com/blog/auto-update-1289/)

[image: Linter Screenshot]

Comment: weird.  it just went from 503 to 502 and now it can read my og:tags somehow.  But the two errors it's saying are false, I provide both, if you look at the code of the page, you'll see.

Comment: what in the world? Why would the Facebook object linter be showing you something different from me? It's still showing me a 503, and totally different warnings.